# Compose Preview's bottom navigation bar color become transparent or white

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, preview, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I have quite a peculiar issue. I am currently making tutorial videos and I am using `@Preview(showSystemUi = true)` in my preview. Yesterday I think I made some adjustments in the settings (in my mac, sorry I'm not sure). But in short, the issue I am having is now my compose preview's bottom bar is white-ish (you can see the bottom bar icon's color is slightly whiter than the bar's color in the first picture).

[image]

Just yesterday, it used to be like this:
[image]

Does anyone know which settings caused this to happen? Thank you

UPDATE:
I found this colors.xml file containing colors (details here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml), I tried to force edit the value of the color in this file, but still no luck

```
<!-- Color for system bars -->
<color name="navigation_bar_compatible">@android:color/black</color>
<!-- This uses non-regular transparent intentionally. It is used to tell if the transparent
     color is set by the framework or not. -->
<color name="navigation_bar_default">#00808080</color>
```