Compose Preview - System UI's Bottom Row Navigation Background and Buttons are all White with @Preview(showSystemUi = true)
I'm working on a project with Jetpack Compose and found out that you can add showSystemUi = true in a @Preview annotation so see the Status Bar and the System UI Bottom Navigation Bar (Recent, Home, Back). However, I've found that when adding showSystemUi = true to my Preview, both the background color and button color of the System Bottom Navigation Bar is white, making the whole thing just look like a blank white bar. The background color of the Navigation Bar should be Black, with White buttons.
Has anyone else experienced this? How do I fix this? Searching on this on Google was extremely difficult, but I managed to find this Stack Overflow question where the author had the same problem from one month ago, but unfortunately they deleted their question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78199873/compose-previews-bottom-navigation-bar-color-become-transparent-or-white.
Clean -> Build and Invalidate Caches didn't work. Adding showBackground = true/false to @Preview does nothing. Switching between Light Mode and Dark Mode for the Preview also does nothing. I've tried updating all the dependencies in my Gradle file as well, which had no effect. Disabling the dynamicColor code in Theme.kt, and commenting out the code to change the Status Bar Color did nothing either. I have no idea what's causing this.
I'm using Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1. Below is a minimal reproducible example. I literally just created a brand new Empty Activity project, and the only thing I modified in the entire project was that I changed the @Preview(showBackground = true) to @Preview(showSystemUi = true).
You can barely see it, but the Recent, Home, and Back buttons are barely visible, and the background color of the System Bottom Navigation Bar is white. Here's a link to a screenshot. I don't have enough rep to embed it in the post properly.
All white System Navigation Bar Screenshot
EDIT: This only happens in the Preview in Android Studio. This does not happen when I run the app on an Emulator or Physical Device.
Here's the code.
MainActivity.kt - only changed @Preview(showBackground = true) to @Preview(showSystemUi = true)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MinimalReproducibleExampleTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MinimalReproducibleExampleTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

Theme.kt - Completely unmodified
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun MinimalReproducibleExampleTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}


Did you run on any actual device or emulator? If you don't, make sure it's happening on a real device. sometimes preview with the system UI element doesn't render properly. If so then maybe I can help you. first you have to confirm.

@MehediHasan It doesn't happen when I build the App to a Physical Device or Emulator. It only happens during the Preview in Android Studio. Do you have an idea of what might be causing this to happen only during the Preview?
Also, I've edited my original post to include the fact that this only happens in the Android Studio Preview. Thanks for pointing out the clarification opportunity.

Facing same issue
